# Bootstrap - Clear selected file using jquery - data-dismiss?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

So I have this div dedicated to being an image uploader. I have a div within that will show when a file is chosen. I also have `<a>` that I want to get rid of and just clear out the uploaded field using jQuery.

Does anyone know how? I `.bind()`'d a click event to the `<a>` but it didn't work... (plus I want to get rid of the link all together) I believe it's because the "active ingredient" is the `data-dismiss="fileupload"` part of the `<a>`.

How can I fire this bad boy using code rather then an anchor tag?

**Here's my code:**

```
<div id="fileuploader" class="fileupload fileupload-new" data-provides="fileupload">
    <div class="fileupload-new thumbnail" style="max-height: 215px; max-width: 175px;">
        <img src="http://www.placehold.it/175x215/EFEFEF/AAAAAA&text=no+image" />
    </div>
    <div class="fileupload-preview fileupload-exists thumbnail" style="max-height: 215px; max-width: 175px; line-height: 20px;">

    </div>
    <div>
        <span class="btn btn-file">
            <span class="fileupload-new">Select image</span>
            <span class="fileupload-exists">Change</span>
            <form>
                <input type="file" name="chosenfile" id="chosenfile"/>
            </form>
        </span>
        <a href="#" id="remove" class="btn fileupload-exists" data-dismiss="fileupload">Remove</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you're looking to do, but I think you want to use the click function like this...

```
$('#remove').click(function(){
    $('#chosenfile').val('');
})
```

[**Here's a demo**](http://bootply.com/61108)