# Uploaded files cannot be posted after remove or change in Bootstrap File input

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, jquery-file-upload

I use [Bootstrap File Input](http://www.jasny.net/bootstrap/javascript/#fileinput) in an ASP.NET MVC5 application as explained on [Uploading a File (Or Files) With ASP.NET MVC](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/07/16/uploading-files-with-aspnetmvc.aspx/).

***View:***

```
<input type="file" name="files" id="file1" >
<a href="javascript:;" id="file1Remove" class="btn red fileinput-exists" data-dismiss="fileinput"> Remove </a>

<input type="file" name="files" id="file2" >
<a href="javascript:;" id="file2Remove" class="btn red fileinput-exists" data-dismiss="fileinput"> Remove </a>

<input type="file" name="files" id="file3" >
<a href="javascript:;" id="file3Remove" class="btn red fileinput-exists" data-dismiss="fileinput"> Remove </a>
```

***Controller:***

```
public ActionResult Insert([Bind(Exclude = null)] IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files)
{
    ...
}
```

I can post the images properly to the Controller via AJAX, however when I remove or change an image the other images are posted to the Controller null as shown below (in this scenario I selected 3 photos and then remove one of them before submitting form). Does anybody know how to fix it?

[image]

Comment: Not familiar with that plugin, but should the `data-dismiss` attribute in the `<a>`  have a relationship to the associated file input?

Comment: Not sure, but I also tried without data-dismiss using a click event for removing file. Actually the problem is that I cannot clear or reset the file input properly using many of approach i.e. [this](http://webtips.krajee.com/clear-html-file-input-value-ie-using-javascript/) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16473227/bootstrap-clear-selected-file-using-jquery-data-dismiss). What do you think?

Comment: Don't have time to check the source code, but have you tried just wrapping each file input and its associated link inside a container (the second example in the link you gave - I assume it will then clear the file input within the container and not the others)

Comment: And as a side note, if you want a bit more flexibility, you might be interested in [this](https://github.com/stephenmuecke/mvc-filehelper)

Comment: Yes, I will wrap but for the first time I just wanted to test with the first one. However it does not clear file input.

Comment: But your code is not the same as in the linked examples :)

Comment: For your previous comment mvc-filehelper seems to be very nice but I need to image preview for all of the uploaded images. Is there another plugin you know that performs this requirements? Or shall I modify your plugin?

Comment: Yes, but the code posted here is just one version of my code (I modified many times).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138302/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-clint-eastwood).

Comment: @StephenMuecke Could you please undelete your answer on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46560515/how-to-create-dynamic-menu-using-tree